# Puma will not start from Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, puma

I am currently running into an issue when trying to run `docker-compose up`. I have Puma in my Gemfile but am getting the following error.

```
web_1 | Puma starting in single mode...

web_1 | * Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller

web_1 | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5

web_1 | * Environment: development

web_1 | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000

web_1 | bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)

web_1 | Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
```

I understand that it may not have the tmp/pids file because of how I am starting my server. However, in my Dockerfile, I am creating this directory so it should not be getting this error anymore. Any ideas as to why I am still getting this error?

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6-alpine3.11
RUN apk add --update --virtual runtime-deps libffi-dev readline tzdata git
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile* ./
RUN apk add --virtual build-deps build-base libc-dev linux-headers libxml2-dev libxslt-dev readline-dev && \
    apk add --update ruby-nokogiri && \
    gem install bundler:2.1.4 && \
    bundle install --jobs=2 && \
    apk del build-deps
ENV APP_HOME /app
COPY . $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir -p tmp/pids
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle","exec","puma","-C","config/puma.rb"]
```

Comment: Can you confirm that a directory of /app/tmp/pids has been created and there is no existing server.pid file in that directory? Generally boot scripts remove that file before starting the server.

Comment: Looks like the output from this command is blank `RUN echo $(ls -1 /tmp/pids)`

Comment: try again on /app/tmp/pids

Comment: `ls: /app/tmp/pids: No such file or directory`

Comment: I switched the mkdir over to `RUN mkdir -p /app/tmp/pids` and now the output from the echo is blank again. Could this be a permissions issue that is causing this not to create?

Comment: Also what is the value of the `pidfile` element of `puma.rb`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223523/discussion-between-trenton-tyler-and-3dprintscanner).